# How to play video and audio from a video file in Java

Tags: java, video, lwjgl

I understand this question has been asked many times before, but after searching all of the answers seem to be outdated (by two or more years) so I thought it reasonable to ask it again.

What libraries are available to read and display video files (such as .avi and similar) in java? I am currently using lwjgl, and cannot easily change to a different library, so please limit suggestions to those compatible with lwjgl.

What I'm trying to do is create a fullscreen display using lwjgl, display the video (with audio synced) as an intro, then either when the video is finished or forcefully skipped continue to the main menu.

Comment: *"but after searching all of the answers seem to be outdated (by two or more years) so I thought it reasonable to ask it again."*  Maybe if you list the APIs that you discovered in that search, otherwise this seems like a 'give me a list I could obtain from Google" type question.  Note especially that [Stack Overflow is not a List for All Things](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128561/155831).

Comment: Xuggler, FMJ, JMF, Fobs4JMF, JFFMPEG, FFMPEG-Java, VLCJ.

Comment: That about sums it up, so long as you realize that FMJ & Fobs4FMJ are both based on (extensions to) JMF, & that there is "FFMPEG" (not Java based), and "JFFMPEG" (the Java based implementation of FFMPEG).  The term FFMPEG-Java has no meaning that I understand.

Comment: @AndrewThompson [FFMPEG-Java](http://fmj-sf.net/ffmpeg-java/getting_started.php) wraps FFMPEG using JNA.